# Populate Treeview using List of Items

Tags: vb.net, treeview

Good Day,

I have two List of objects (say for e.g. MyObjList as new List(of Integer) ) and based on their indices I want to build up a treeview starting from item 0 and end with last item in the list. I want these objects to appear something like below. I can add first node but then after that can't figure how to add next node as child of each previously added node (if that makes sense). Would appreciate your help.
I have attached an image to give better understanding of how I want it to look like as against to what I am getting at the moment based on below answers.[image: treeview populated with two lists of objects]

```
0-->
    1
     --> 
        2
         -->
           3--> 
               4


      Dim myObjList As New List(Of integer)
            myObjList.Add("0")
            myObjList.Add("1")
            myObjList.Add("2")
            myObjList.Add("3")
            myObjList.Add("4")
```

Can we achieve this?

[image: Can we achieve this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have got this right, you are trying to add `Nodes` so that the `TreeView` looks like this:

[image]

This is what it would look like manually:

```
TreeView1.Nodes.Add(list(0).ToString())
TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(list(1).ToString())
TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(list(2).ToString())
TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes(0).Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(list(3).ToString())
TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes(0).Nodes(0).Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(list(4).ToString())
```

This of course is a real pain and isn't scalable. What I would look at instead is *recursively* adding child `Nodes` to the `TreeView` like such:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim list As New List(Of Integer)

    Private Sub AddMoreChildren(ByVal parent As TreeNode)

        If parent.Level < list.Count - 1 Then
            Dim child As New TreeNode(list(parent.Level + 1).ToString())

            parent.Nodes.Add(child)

            AddMoreChildren(child)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        list.Add(0)
        list.Add(1)
        list.Add(2)
        list.Add(3)
        list.Add(4)

        Dim root As New TreeNode(list.First.ToString())
        AddMoreChildren(root)
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(root)

    End Sub

End Class
```

From the code above you will achieve the same result as seen shown in the screenshot.

The beauty of this is that the code will continue to call `AddMoreChildren` until all items in the `List` have been added.

**Edited to incorporate two lists**

If you have two lists then what I would look at doing is bringing them together to create a distinct `List` using [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386979(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Note that I have now changed my `List`s to be of type `String` for this example and no longer need to use `.ToString` when setting the value.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim firstList As New List(Of String)
    Dim secondList As New List(Of String)
    Dim mainList As New List(Of String)

    Private Sub AddMoreChildren(ByVal parent As TreeNode)

        If parent.Level < mainList.Count - 1 Then
            Dim child As New TreeNode(mainList(parent.Level + 1))

            parent.Nodes.Add(child)

            AddMoreChildren(child)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        firstList.Add("S")
        firstList.Add("A3")
        firstList.Add("U13")
        firstList.Add("ABC")
        firstList.Add("PQ")
        firstList.Add("1234")

        secondList.Add("S")
        secondList.Add("A3")
        secondList.Add("U13")
        secondList.Add("XYZ")
        secondList.Add("ST")
        secondList.Add("5678")

        mainList = firstList.Concat(secondList).Distinct().ToList()

        Dim root As New TreeNode(mainList.First)
        AddMoreChildren(root)
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(root)

    End Sub

End Class
```

This will give you the following output:

[image]

**Edit based on OP's update**

This is what the OP is after based on the update:

[image]

This requires a little more code and isn't as neat but it does do the job. In this I have to bring in another variable called `index`. This is purely to keep track of the current index in `mainList` instead of using `If parent.Level`.

I also have to manipulate `mainList` quite a bit so I'll try to explain in bits.

First let's use [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx). This is used to get a list where values are found in both `firstList` and `secondList` leaving us with **S**, **A3** and **U13**:

```
Dim root As TreeNode
mainList = firstList.Intersect(secondList).ToList()
root = New TreeNode(mainList.First)
```

Now that we have these let's go ahead and add them to the `TreeView`:

```
index = 1
AddMoreChildren(root)
TreeView1.Nodes.Add(root)
```

I set `index` to **1** here because I already have the root node and want to start at **A3** when I go into `AddMoreChildren`. There has also been a slight change to the `AddMoreChildren` method:

```
Private Sub AddMoreChildren(ByVal parent As TreeNode)

    If index < mainList.Count Then
        Dim child As New TreeNode(mainList(index).ToString())

        parent.Nodes.Add(child)

        index += 1

        AddMoreChildren(child)
    End If

End Sub
```

> Note the use of `index` now instead of `parent.Level`.

Next, since you want to branch out from **U13** we need to get the index of this. This is done quite simply:

```
Dim indexOfLastNode As Integer = mainList.Count - 1
```

Next we set the **U13** as the root node:

```
root = GetLastAddedChildNode(TreeView1.Nodes(0), indexOfLastNode)
```

The code for `GetLastAddedChildNode` is:

```
Private Function GetLastAddedChildNode(ByVal parentNode As TreeNode,
                                       ByVal level As Integer) As TreeNode

    Dim newNode As New TreeNode

    For Each node As TreeNode In parentNode.Nodes
        If node.Level = level Then
            newNode = node
            Exit For
        End If
        newNode = GetLastAddedChildNode(node, level)
    Next

    Return newNode

End Function
```

Then we manipulate the `mainList` so that we get all values from `firstList` that aren't in `secondList`. This leaves us with **ABC**, **PQ** and **1234**. We do this by using [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx). We can then call `AddMoreChildren` and add **ABC**, **PQ** and **1234** to **U13**.

> Note, don't forget to reset `index` to 0 before you call `AddMoreChildren` so that we can get all the items in `mainList` added.

We then do the same for the `secondList` using `Except`.  Here is the full code in one full swoop. It may make more sense:

```
 Public Class Form1

    Dim firstList As New List(Of String)
    Dim secondList As New List(Of String)
    Dim mainList As New List(Of String)

    Dim index As Integer

    Private Sub AddMoreChildren(ByVal parent As TreeNode)

        If index < mainList.Count Then
            Dim child As New TreeNode(mainList(index).ToString())

            parent.Nodes.Add(child)

            index += 1

            AddMoreChildren(child)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Function GetLastAddedChildNode(ByVal parentNode As TreeNode,
                                           ByVal level As Integer) As TreeNode

        Dim newNode As New TreeNode

        For Each node As TreeNode In parentNode.Nodes
            If node.Level = level Then
                newNode = node
                Exit For
            End If
            newNode = GetLastAddedChildNode(node, level)
        Next

        Return newNode

    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        firstList.Add("S")
        firstList.Add("A3")
        firstList.Add("U13")
        firstList.Add("ABC")
        firstList.Add("PQ")
        firstList.Add("1234")

        secondList.Add("S")
        secondList.Add("A3")
        secondList.Add("U13")
        secondList.Add("XYZ")
        secondList.Add("ST")
        secondList.Add("5478")

        Dim root As TreeNode
        mainList = firstList.Intersect(secondList).ToList()
        root = New TreeNode(mainList.First)

        index = 1
        AddMoreChildren(root)
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(root)

        Dim indexOfLastNode As Integer = mainList.Count - 1

        If TreeView1.Nodes.Count = 1 Then
            root = GetLastAddedChildNode(TreeView1.Nodes(0), indexOfLastNode)

            mainList = firstList.Except(secondList).ToList()
            If root.Text.Equals(firstList(indexOfLastNode)) Then
                index = 0
                AddMoreChildren(root)

                mainList = secondList.Except(firstList).ToList()
                index = 0
                AddMoreChildren(root)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here is a screenshot of the output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Jinx88909, yes. That's what I am after. but instead  0,1,...5. etc I have a type of API Object  that I would be populating in the treeview. I will try your method as well and let you know how it goes.

Comment: thanks, this works too. just one query, how can I add another list with different values but same parent in this one? Both my lists are basically two Hierarchy Paths with common TopNode. These lists may have common top 2-4 nodes after which they diverge. is that possible. With your and @Pro Grammer's code I can get both paths in Treeview but they appear separate.

Comment: @DK2014 If this also works, you should click the Up Arrow to UpVote it.  Upvotes help other users find good posts.

Comment: apologies..will try and post some pics to make it more clear.

Comment: @Jinx88909, I have now attached an image to show how its appearing after incorporating your codes and added some explanation on how I want it. Hope its clear this time.

Comment: Thanks. although this one adds the second list unique items as children after having added first list items. I have used your image and made some changes. Is it something we can do. I am not exactly retrieving this objects directly from database. These items are retrieved in our app via API.

Comment: I have added a new image based in the original post, the blue line shows the split where nodes become different.

Comment: @DK2014 done, think it should be what you are after. It's quite a long answer now so hopefully makes sense. Let me know if you have any further questions. Also note I've deleted comments, just to keep this a little tidier.

Comment: Hi Jinx, great work man. finally made it work.. because I am assigning other properties to treenode like Tag, name(to allow finding node), text and also the image; its took me some time to tweak your new code to my requirements, BUT ITS WORKING!!!!! many thanks.. your help is much appreciated.. now my treeview looks much neat..

Comment: @Jinx88909, I am not sure if you were notified before so adding this comment. Also wanted to thank you for the detailed explanation. Its now more clear to me and will be useful in future. cheers.. :-)

Comment: @DK2014 I was :) it's not a problem, had fun putting the code together. Glad you've managed to incorporate into your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Put together this code for you:

```
Dim tmpNode As TreeNode = Nothing

For Each num In myObjList.Reverse
    Dim newNode = New TreeNode(num.ToString)

    If tmpNode IsNot Nothing Then
        newNode.Nodes.Add(tmpNode)
    End If

    tmpNode = newNode
Next
```

Goes through the list in reverse and adds each node as a child of the last.

EDIT: Did this one too, doesn't require reversing your list

```
Dim topNode As TreeNode = Nothing
Dim latestNode As TreeNode = Nothing

For Each num In myObjList
    Dim tmpNode = New TreeNode(num.ToString)

    If myObjList.IndexOf(num) = 0 Then
        topNode = tmpNode
        latestNode = topNode
    Else
        latestNode.Nodes.Add(tmpNode)
        latestNode = tmpNode
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Many thanks for quick reply. in your second post,can you tell me what "numlist" is? or is it "myObjList"? Also, where do I specify the Treeview name? sorry for basic questions.

Comment: Oh sorry, I used a temporary list `Dim numList = New List(Of Integer) From {0,1,2,3,4,5,6}`. Let me just edit that out :P As for the treeview name, you would just call TreeView.Nodes.Add() and give it whatever your 0 node is

Comment: great. Its working now for me. Just another question. if I now have another list but with different values while the Topnode being same (say 0 in this case), can they both be incorporated in same treeview without having duplicate nodes?

Comment: Absolutely, you would just do the exact same thing, and add it to `TreeView.Nodes` or to `TopNode.Nodes` depending on what you need. Duplicate nodes won't be an issue