# Populate Treeview with data from string split with "\"

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I have a large list which contains value like

```
List(0) = "Drive\First1\Folder2\Folder3"

List(1) = "Drive\Second2"

List(2) = "Drive\SubFolder1\ChildSubFolder"

    Dim List = Split("Drive\First1\Folder2\Folder3", "\")

    ParentNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(List(0))

    For x = 1 To List.Count - 1
        ParentNode.Nodes.Add(List(x))
    Next
```

I am very confused about how to populate treeview control in vb.net

Can someone help me on this? Please. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: [_**Re-asking your question**_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46409872) will definitely not help you get any answers. Although exceptions exist, Stack Overflow is not a coding service. Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Basically what you need to do is split the string at `\ `, keep the first item (index 0) and then add each split entry as a child node under each previous node.

Comment: Dim List = Split("Drive\First1\Folder2\Folder3", "\")

ParentNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(List(0))

For x = 1 To List.Count - 1
      ParentNode.Nodes.Add(List(x))
Next

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate Treeview using List of Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940229/populate-treeview-using-list-of-items)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two loops.  One loop for the list, the second one to loop through the items that are separated by the slash.  The tricky part is to differentiate between a "root node", which belongs to the TreeView control itself, and a "child node" that belongs to a parent node within that collection.

Once you have that figured out, you simply examine to see if the node already exists, and if it does, use that, otherwise, add it to the collection.

```
For Each item As String In List
  Dim activeNode As TreeNode = Nothing
  Dim nodeItems As TreeNodeCollection = Nothing
  Dim subItems() As String = item.Split("\"c)
  For i As Integer = 0 To subItems.Length - 1
    nodeItems = If(i = 0, TreeView1.Nodes, activeNode.Nodes)
    If nodeItems.ContainsKey(subItems(i)) Then
      activeNode = nodeItems(subItems(i))
    Else
      activeNode = nodeItems.Add(subItems(i), subItems(i))
    End If
  Next
Next
```

Comment: Hi LarsTech, Thanks for the answer... It just works.   I don't know why people are in hurry to mark my question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Smith : Because it more or less is a duplicate, and you must always show us what you've tried if you want specific help? (now that you've done that it's fine :) ) -- You see, showing your attempts are quite [**specific guidelines**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of Stack Overflow. Merely [**asking for code**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is usually too broad, as there are too many possible ways to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I too find the answer but my code gives incorrect results... and @LarsTech code works perfectly. Thanks again LarsTech

```
    Dim List(3) As String
    List(0) = "Drive\First1\Folder2\Folder3"
    List(1) = "Drive\Second2"
    List(2) = "Drive\Second3\Folder4"
    List(3) = "xDrive\Folder4\Folder5"

    For Each ListItem In List
        Dim Folders() = Split(ListItem, "\")

        For i = 1 To Folders.Count - 1

            Dim pNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Find(Folders(i - 1), True)

            If pNode.Count = 0 Then
                Dim pNode1 = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(Folders(i - 1), Folders(i - 1))
                pNode1.Nodes.Add(Folders(i), Folders(i))
            Else
                If pNode(0).Nodes.Find(Folders(i), True).Count = 0 Then
                    pNode(0).Nodes.Add(Folders(i), Folders(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
```